# NVM - How to install same Node version but different global versions of NPM using NVM

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have two projects:

- project A: Node 16.10.0 NPM 7.24.2
- project B: Node 16.10.0 NPM 8.10.0

Both require the same version of Node but different versions of NPM. I am wondering if it can be achieved with NVM.

I was able to do it (on **MacOS**) but it is rather hacky

```
nvm use v16.10.0
npm -v      # 7.24.2
which node  # /Users/useriko/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node

# duplicate v16.10.0 folder
ditto ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0 ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0_npm8

nvm use v16.10.0_npm8
npm i -g npm@8.10.0

nvm alias v16_npm7 v16.10.0
nvm alias v16_npm8 v16.10.0_npm8
```

now I can toggle between them

- `nvm use v16_npm7` for npm 7.24.2
- `nvm use v16_npm8` for npm 8.10.0

Is there a better/alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to have the npm version defined in a per-project `.nvmrc` file.

There is a nvm feature request asking for this: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/964.

In the meantime, a proposed workaround is to define a `preinstall` script in your package.json , installing the npm version you need such as:

```
"preinstall": "npm i -g npm@8.10.0"
```

Comment: Thanks! To make this solution work one also needs to enable `nvm` deeper integration
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#deeper-shell-integration

Otherwise, you may end up installing `npm` in an incorrect `node` version if you forgot to switch to the correct `node` version manually